# How can you be notified when the user switches between views?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mdi, mdichild

In an MDI application, when the user switches between views something has to be updated. What's the best message to handle for realizing when this happens?
In my application a document has only one view, but logically I want to get notified when switch is between documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch WM_SETFOCUS in CChildFrame (ChildFrm.h). When a user clicks a view window, or sets focus to a view in another manner, this member function can be a bridge to whatever you need to set in the application.